# Huffman code generator using matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion, huffman-code

I made a huffman code generator(without matlab auto commands),but i have a problem reading the results.

Basicly I built a function that recieves (vec)`gray_levels` and (vec)`histogram`,
and generate from it a vector of probabilities for each gray scale value.
then I built a huffman tree(which seems right becuse the probability of the root is 1).

My assignment was to create a matrix (rows=hist rows , col=number of longest code word+1) and it seems that i get doubled values.

The longest codeword i get is 20 bits long(and it should be 9-10),and i think its not a possible value.

Does anyone has an idea whats wrong with the code?

I used simple recursive function on the tree to extract longest codeword,
and another rcursive function to generate a code for each node in the tree.

Thank you very much!
the code as asked:

```
    function [ codeMat ] = Huffman( gray_levels,hist )

    [entropy,probs]=Entropy(gray_levels,hist); 
    leaves=leaf.empty(decideSize(probs),0);
    j=1;
    for i=1:size(probs,1)
    if(probs(i)~=1) 
    leaves(j).prob=probs(i);
    leaves(j).index=i;
    j=j+1;
    end
    end
    temp=leaves;
    while size(temp,2)>1
    temp=sortAscendByProb(temp);
    node=leaf;
    node.prob=temp(1).prob+temp(2).prob;
    temp(1).code='0';
    temp(2).code='1';
       node.left=temp(1);
       node.right=temp(2);
       temp=temp(3:size(temp,2));
       temp=[node temp];
        end

     root=temp(1);
    codec='';

    longestCodeLen=FindLongestWord(root);
    codeMat=zeros(numel(hist),longestCodeLen+1);
    for i=1:size(codeMat,1)
     codeMat(i,:)=2;
     end

     codeMat=loop(root,codec,codeMat);
     end
```

Comment: "does anyone has an idea whats wrong with the code?" You haven't shown the code.

Comment: From what we can see the problem with the code is that it does not exist.

Comment: You'll need to show us your code and the inputs you used. We can't even say if 20 bits is a reasonable codeword length from the information given here.

Comment: If you don't share your code - we can't help.

Comment: Add proper indentation. I can't tell what should be inside the if after your first for loop. Also add the implementation of the functions you used in this code.